# Liquibase addAutoIncrement error with Postgresql

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, liquibase, liquibase-hibernate

I am having a problem when trying to create autoincrement with the liquibase along with the spring boot with following error

```
<addAutoIncrement 
        columnDataType="bigint"
        columnName="id"
        incrementBy="1"
        startWith="4"
        tableName="jhi_user" />



Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: cross-database references are not implemented: "public.public.jhi_user_id_seq"
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2455)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2155)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:288)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:430)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:356)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:303)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeCachedSql(PgStatement.java:289)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:266)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:262)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:95)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java)
at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor$ExecuteStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcExecutor.java:307)
... 17 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Try to add `schemaName` attribute. It looks like you have multiple schemas or databases with same tables.

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into the same issue. A downgrade to 3.5.1 helped me.

This may be your issue:

https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-2975

Edit: 3.5.5 works as well